# Programmatical approach in Java for file comparison

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, distance, file-comparison

What would be the best approach to compare two hexadecimal file signatures against each other for similarities.

More specifically, what I would like to do is to take the hexadecimal representation of an .exe file and compare it against a series of virus signature. For this approach I plan to break the file (exe) hex representation into individual groups of N chars (ie. 10 hex chars) and do the same with the virus signature. I am aiming to perform some sort of heuristics and therefore statistically check whether this exe file has X% of similarity against the known virus signature.

The simplest and likely very wrong way I thought of doing this is, to compare exe[n, n-1] against virus [n, n-1] where each element in the array is a sub array, and therefore exe1[0,9] against virus1[0,9]. Each subset will be graded statistically.

As you can realize there would be a massive number of comparisons and hence very very slow. So I thought to ask whether you guys can think of a better approach to do such comparison, for example implementing different data structures together.

*This is for a project am doing for my BSc where am trying to develop an algorithm to detect polymorphic malware, this is only one part of the whole system, where the other is based on genetic algorithms to evolve the static virus signature. Any advice, comments, or general information such as resources are very welcome.*

---

**Definition**: Polymorphic malware (virus, worm, ...) maintains the same functionality and payload as their "original" version, while having apparently different structures (variants). They achieve that by code obfuscation and thus altering their hex signature. Some of the techniques used for polymorphism are; format alteration (insert remove blanks), variable renaming, statement rearrangement, junk code addition, statement replacement (x=1 changes to x=y/5 where y=5), swapping of control statements. So much like the flu virus mutates and therefore vaccination is not effective, polymorphic malware mutates to avoid detection.

---

**Update:** After the advise you guys gave me in regards what reading to do; I did that, but it somewhat confused me more. I found several distance algorithms that can apply to my problem, such as;

- Longest common subsequence
- Levenshtein algorithm
- Needleman–Wunsch algorithm
- Smith–Waterman algorithm
- Boyer Moore algorithm
- Aho Corasick algorithm

But now I don't know which to use, they all seem to do he same thing in different ways. I will continue to do research so that I can understand each one better; but in the mean time could you give me your opinion on `which might be more suitable` so that I can give it priority during my research and to study it deeper.

---

**Update 2:** I ended up using an amalgamation of the LCSubsequence, LCSubstring and Levenshtein Distance. Thank you all for the suggestions.

There is a copy of the finished paper on [GitHub](https://github.com/carlosnasillo/Hybrid-Genetic-Algorithm)

Comment: Definitely read up on "Longest common substring" and "Longest common subsequence"

Comment: @Pace; cheers buddy, ill do that

Comment: @Pace; man you where right on the money! i was looking also for something like that, i just didnt know how to search for it. thanks!!!

Comment: Guys I included an update. thanks in advance for all your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For algorithms like these I suggest you look into the bioinformatics area. There is a similar problem setting there in that you have large files (genome sequences) in which you are looking for certain signatures (genes, special well-known short base sequences, etc.).

Also for considering polymorphic malware, this sector should offer you a lot, because in biology it seems similarly difficult to get exact matches. (Unfortunately, I am not aware of appropriate approximative searching/matching algorithms to point you to.)

One example from this direction would be to adapt something like the [Aho Corasick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm) algorithm in order to search for several malware signatures at the same time.

Similarly, algorithms like the [Boyer Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer_moore) algorithm give you fantastic search runtimes especially for longer sequences (average case of O(N/M) for a text of size N in which you look for a pattern of size M, i.e. sublinear search times).

Answer (score 2):

A number of papers have been published on finding near duplicate documents in a large corpus of documents in the context of websearch. I think you will find them useful. For example, see 
this [presentation](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgraphics.stanford.edu%2F~niloy%2Fresearch%2Ffingerprinting%2Fpaper_docs%2Ffingerprint_poster.pdf&ei=5hXQTKueGoGC8gby2M2tBw&usg=AFQjCNH2HooExijG2hsqUOZOJjH1-xWUIA).

Answer (score 1):

There has been a serious amount of research recently into automating the detection of duplicate bug reports in bug repositories. This is essentially the same problem you are facing. The difference is that you are using binary data. They are similar problems because you will be looking for strings that have the same basic pattern, even though the patterns may have some slight differences. A straight-up distance algorithm probably won't serve you well here.

This paper gives a good summary of the problem as well as some approaches in its citations that have been tried.

ftp://ftp.computer.org/press/outgoing/proceedings/Patrick/apsec10/data/4266a366.pdf

Answer (score 1):

As somebody has pointed out, similarity with known string and bioinformatics problem might help. Longest common substring is very brittle, meaning that one difference can halve the length of such a string. You need a form of string alignment, but more efficient than Smith-Waterman. I would try and look at programs such as BLAST, BLAT or MUMMER3 to see if they can fit your needs. Remember that the default parameters, for these programs, are based on a biology application (how much to penalize an insertion or a substitution for instance), so you should probably look at re-estimating parameters based on your application domain, possibly based on a training set. This is a known problem because even in biology different applications require different parameters (based, for instance, on the evolutionary distance of two genomes to compare). It is also possible, though, that even at default one of these algorithms might produce usable results. Best of all would be to have a generative model of how viruses change and that could guide you in an optimal choice for a distance and comparison algorithm.