# How to read content of .EXE file in Java

Tags: java, binary, executable, iostream

*What are the possible options and the most appropiate for reading an executable file in Java.*

I want produce the hexadecimal representation of an .exe file. Im thinking of reading the file in binary and then doing the conversion. But how can i read the .exe?

Comment: Not sure I follow.  You want to reproduce the functionality of a standard hex editor?

Comment: @Kirk: well not really, this question is linked to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4068218/programmatical-approach-in-java-for-file-comparison.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) read the file in as bytes. use

```
   BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream( new File("bin.exe") ) )
```

2) convert each byte to hex format.

```
    static final String HEXES = "0123456789ABCDEF";
  public static String getHex( byte [] raw ) {
    if ( raw == null ) {
      return null;
    }
    final StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder( 2 * raw.length );
    for ( final byte b : raw ) {
      hex.append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0xF0) >> 4))
         .append(HEXES.charAt((b & 0x0F)));
    }
    return hex.toString();
  }
```

Comment: thanks so much buddy, more than anything i was wanted to know if java could handle executables, which is now clear. Thanks for going that extra mile.

Comment: Every programming language should be able to handle binary format. Think of it this way. Everything is represented in binary form. 0s and 1s. So, one can safely assume that a programming language can read in 0s and 1s and transform them into something simple like hex.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**
It didn't occur to me that you'd want it as a string.  Modified the example to do so.  It should perform slightly better than using a `BufferedReader` since we're doing the buffering ourselves.

```
public String binaryFileToHexString(final String path)
    throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
{
    final int bufferSize = 512;
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // open the file
    FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(path);
    int bytesRead;

    // read a block
    while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buffer)) > 0)
    {
        // append the block as hex
        for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
        {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X", buffer[i]));
        }
    }
    stream.close();

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An `InputStream` in Java is the primary class for reading binary files.  You can use a `FileInputStream` to read bytes from a file.  You could then read in each byte with the `read()` method and display that byte as 2 hex characters if you wanted.